# Is it possible to have a UIPickerView and a UIDatePicker from the same UITextField in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I'm new to Swift so please bear with me.

Firstly, let me explain my app layout:

I have a Text Field on the screen, with a Label and a button. I am asking the user 3 questions - these questions are displayed using the 'Label', and the next question appears each time the user presses the Next 'Button' (The questions are populated from an array).

One of the the questions needs to populate a Picker View (so the user can pick an option).
One of the questions uses a normal keyboard.
And the last question I need to use a Date Picker.

Is this possible to do? And if so, could you show me how to add it to my code below please?

```
let questions = ["What is your title?", "What is your full name?", "When were you born?"]

var currentQuestionIndex = 0

let placeholder = ["Title", "Full name", "Date of birth"]

var currentPlaceholderIndex = 0

@IBAction func nextButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    textField.hidden = false
    textField.placeholder = placeholder[currentPlaceholderIndex]
    barImage.hidden = false

    // Reset text field to have no text
    textField.text = ""


    questionLabel.text = questions[currentQuestionIndex]

    // Displays the questions in array
    if currentQuestionIndex < questions.count {
        ++currentQuestionIndex

        // Displays the placeholder text in the textfield
        if currentPlaceholderIndex < placeholder.count {
            ++currentPlaceholderIndex

        }

        buttonLabel.setTitle("Next", forState: UIControlState.Normal)


    }

    else {

       //Add some logic here to run whenever the user has answered all the questions.

    }

  }
```

thanks for your help!

Nick

NEW CODE BELOW (from 6th April 2015):

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

```
var pickerData = ["Mr", "Mrs", "Miss", "Ms", "Doctor"]

var questions = ["What is your title?", "What is your name?", "What is your DOB?"]

var currentQuestionIndex = 0

var datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
var pickerView:UIPickerView = UIPickerView()

@IBOutlet var buttonLabel: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var questionsLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

@IBAction func textFieldEditing(sender: UITextField) {

    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    sender.inputView = datePickerView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerValueChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}

func datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    var dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateformatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
    textField.text = dateformatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}

@IBAction func nextButton(sender: UIButton) {

    textField.text = ""
    textField.hidden = false
    buttonLabel.setTitle("Next", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    questionsLabel.text = questions[currentQuestionIndex]

    if currentQuestionIndex < questions.count {

        currentQuestionIndex++ 
    }

    else {
        //println("questions are complete")
    }
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    switch currentQuestionIndex {

    case 0:
        self.view.addSubview(datePickerView)

    case 2:
        self.view.addSubview(pickerView)
    default:
        println("Test")
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    buttonLabel.setTitle("Start", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    textField.hidden = true
    questionsLabel.text = ""
    textField.delegate = self
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)

}


func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

return pickerData.count

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
return pickerData[row]

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

textField.text = pickerData[row]
pickerView.hidden = true

}
```

}

Comment: Make an IBOulet for every element that you want to use, check for which questione you need said element, show this element and hide the others

Comment: @Nick89 Just went back to see if you could use the solution but I see problems in your code. The function textFieldDidBeginEditing(:) that you did put into your nextButton(:) should be out of this function. textFieldDidBeginEditing(:) is a method declared in UITextFieldDelegate that you conformed to and now you should implement it. Remember, methods declared(not defined) in protocols are just abstract and real implementation comes in your ViewController.

Comment: @Nick89 Let me know if you have any problem and don't hesitate to ask

Comment: @user4130613 - Firstly thanks for your help with all of this! I have started a new project to hopefully keep it tidier. Please see all my new code above. As far as i can work out, i have updated everything as you have said to (i think!), but it doesn't work as expected. All i see is a DatePicker overtime i press the textField. I don't see the pickerView for the first question and the keyboard for the 2nd question...? thanks

Comment: Hey @user4130613 - i was wondering if you had chance to look at the above? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on `currentQuestionIndex` you can add either `UIPickerView` or `UIDatePicker` to your `UITextField` instance

```
switch currentQuestionIndex {
case 0: 
  // TODO: Add UIPickerView
case 2:
  // TODO: Add UIDatePicker
}
```

Edit: More explanation

At first, conform to `UITextFieldDelegate` and implement `textFieldDidBeginEditing(:)` 
You must implement that method because you wanna get notify when the UITextField instance get first responder state

Also, set `UITextField` instance's `delegate` property to `self` or what ever instance/object that you want to put and implement `textFieldDidBeginEditing(:)`

Then write this code

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
  switch currentQuestionIndex {
    case 0: 
      // TODO: Add UIPickerView
      // Add it for example at the bottom your view self.view.addSubview(pickerViewInstance)
      // or add it as the subview of UIPopoverController instance that is added to your UITextField instance 
    case 2:
      // TODO: Add UIDatePicker
      // Add it for example at the bottom your view self.view.addSubview(datePickerInstance)
      // or add it as the subview of UIPopoverController instance that is added to your UITextField instance 
  }
}
```

Remember to remove added view when you want add another view to your UIPopoverViewController.

Edit: Add real world implementation

```
class NewCaseViewController : UIViewController {
    . . .

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField // TODO: Initialize it properly in designated initializer
    var popoverController: UIPopoverController! // TODO: Initialize it

    . . .
}


class PopoverContentManager : UIViewController {
    . . .

    var pickerView: UIPickerView // TODO: Initialize it properly
    var datePicker: UIDatePicker // TODO: Initialize it properly

    . . .
}

extension NewCaseViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        println(__FUNCTION__)

        var popover = PopoverContentManager()

        switch self.currentQuestionIndex {
            case 0:
                popover.datePicker.hidden = true

                self.popoverController = init(contentViewController: popOver)

                self.popoverController.presentPopoverFromRect(self.textField.bounds, inView: self.textField, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown, animated: true)

                self.popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(120, 90)
            case 1:
                popover.pickerView.hidden = true

                self.popoverController = init(contentViewController: popOver)

                self.popoverController.presentPopoverFromRect(self.textField.bounds, inView: self.textField, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown, animated: true)

                self.popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(120, 90)
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks user4130613, Ive added some more info above as i am getting some errors...thank you

Comment: sorry i'm still having trouble, and would really like to understand where i'm going wrong. I have added my new code in the question above so you can see all my code. I'm getting an error saying 'Use of unresolved identifier 'pickerViewInstance' and 'datePickerInstance'. I would really appreciate your help in understanding what i'm doing wrong, as i'm new to all this and am keen to get my head around it! Thanks in advance

Comment: @Nick89 This is because you haven't defined pickerViewInstance and datePickerInstance in ViewController class so define them and initialize them in ViewController